# python 2.7 SimPy ImportError

Tags: python, python-2.7, importerror, simpy

I have a virtualenv with python 2.7 and pip 9.0.1
I have installed SimPy with
pip install SimPy

but when i try to import import SimPy

```
>>> import SimPy
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named SimPy
```

Comment: try my solution

Comment: eyllanesc your solution works.
but I have an old simmulation file which was written in SimPy 2.3. If I install SimPy 2.3 then I will also have to edit many other methods that were called in that old file because those method's name or parameter have also changed.
So using simpy 2.3 was the easiest way to get started for me.

Comment: You should point out the version of simpy and the program that generates the error

Comment: Edit your question with these requirements

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had a simulation file for simpy 2.3.1. but when installed `pip install SimPy`
It installed simpy 3.1 which was different from 2.3.1

So I had to install SimPy by pip install SimPy==2.3.1
and it solved the problem

Comment: Note, that SimPy 2 is deprecated and no longer supported.

Comment: It was an assignment from an old code. So I did not have any choice but to use SimPy 2

Answer (score 6):

read the [docs](https://simpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/), change SimPy to simpy

```
>> import simpy
...
```